# gactions cli x509 certificate signed by unknown authority error

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm getting a **x509 certificate signed by unknown authority error** when trying to update my action package via the 'gactions' CLI - please help.

It was working a few days ago fine and I don't think I've changed anything on my end. I'm on the most recent version (2.1.3 - x86_64) of the actions CLI, on Mac High Sierra 10.13.3.

I've searched on stackoverflow and google for an answer but can't work it out.

Thanks

**What I'm seeing...** (updated to include --verbose output)

> Checking for updates...
>
> Error: Get https://dl.google.com/gactions/updates.json: x509:
>   certificate signed by unknown authority POST
>   /v2/agents/gactions-da5a7:batchUpdateAllDraftActionPackages HTTP/1.1
>   Host: actions.googleapis.com User-Agent: Gactions-CLI/2.1.3 (darwin;
>   amd64; stable/dff629ae63XXXXXXXXXXXXX9274524569714e6) Content-Length:
>   567 Content-Type: application/json Accept-Encoding: gzip
>
> {"localizedActionPackages":{"en":{"actions":[{"description":"Default
>   Welcome
>   Intent","fulfillment":{"conversationName":"heythere"},"intent":{"name":"actions.intent.MAIN","trigger":{"queryPatterns":["talk
>   to
>   heythere"]}},"name":"MAIN"}],"conversations":{"heythere":{"fulfillmentApiVersion":2,"name":"heythere","url":"https://XXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXX"}},"locale":"en","name":"agents/XXXXXXXXXXX"}
>
> Reading credentials from: creds.data
>
> Gactions needs access to your Google account. Please copy & paste the
>   URL below into a web browser and follow the instructions there. Then
>   copy and paste the authorization code from the browser back here.
>
> Visit this URL: 
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=23XXXXXXXX06-o6vu1tXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX396e2d0c.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Factions.builder&state=state
>
> Enter authorization code:
>   4/AADzNzL7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX5jIs4JCWR-5T-TztD9IamE
>
> 2018/02/24
>   15:23:01 Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: x509:
>   certificate signed by unknown authority

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output from using the --verbose command? so something like: `gactions --verbose update --project $PROJECT --action_package action.json` (and, again, mask out what might look like sensitive tokens and identifiers)

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner I've updated the post with the --verbose output I hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that the SSL certificates you're using are either untrusted or out of date. If you are setting certificates yourself on this machine, possibly due to your own development work, `gactions` could be picking one of these up. You may want to check the following:

- Make sure your `SSL_CERT_FILE` and `SSL_CERT_DIR` environment variables aren't set. If they are, unset them.
- I've seen references to issues using Docker, Go, and SSL. If you're doing this in a container, this might be part of the problem you're seeing. (I don't know the combination of technologies well enough to understand the discussions.)

Comment: Hmm I've checked and those env variables aren't set, and I'm not in docker or anything weird just running on Mac.

Comment: I've seen the same references online but couldn't piece together anything helpful. Thanks for the help anyway - maybe someone will know a solution or perhaps it's just a temporary issue.

Comment: It may be related to the Wi-Fi connection, if there's an intermediary which is intercepting traffic.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the comment. No I'm afraid I'm at home not in a corporate office with a firewall or anything. Plus it used to work here fine.

Comment: Only thing I can think of that I did recently... I updated minikube via homebrew to the latest version. Just mentioning in case that could have some how messed with my SSL certificates somehow but I don't know how to check that.

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner and Nick. It seems that a restart or waiting a day has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting seemed to solve this in my case. That, or it was a temporary issue on Google's side. If you're encountering this, try a restart.